# Apply curtains/blinds to an area in an image

Tags: android

I am trying to create an app similar to "Kresta" app on Android.
I attached some images related to what I want to do.
I have tried searching but nothing has come up so far because I don't know what is this technique called. Please guide in the right direction.
Thanks.

I can probably add the curtains using bitmaps and canvas, I only need guidance in adding that editable yellow area.

[image: User will select an area to apply curtains]
[image: Curtains applied]

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at some of the libraries that are focused on image manipulation/transformation. The question you ask is very broad. Perhaps starting here will help you refine your search and/or questions: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/47

Comment: Thank you. Thing is, I don't think it's image processing as the user can select any area he/she likes and curtains are added on that area. Like an overlay.

Comment: What I want to know is how to get that yellow frame area. I can then probably add curtains using bitmaps and canvas